# Vim-easy-align: how to align delimeter on right

Tags: alignment, plugin-easy-align

Fo example, this piece of code in rails:

```
  t.string :receipt_number
  t.timestamp :transaction_timestamp
  t.string :transaction_type
  t.decimal :cash_amount
  t.decimal :card_amount
```

Now, I want new code should be:

```
  t.string      :receipt_number
  t.timestamp   :transaction_timestamp
  t.string      :transaction_type
  t.decimal     :cash_amount
  t.decimal     :card_amount
```

I have tried align left/right/center, but It seems not work.

first case:

```
  t.string:    receipt_number
  t.timestamp: transaction_timestamp
  t.string:    transaction_type
  t.decimal:   cash_amount
  t.decimal:   card_amount
  t.decimal:   voucher_amount
  t.decimal:   total_amount
  t.int:       sa_id
  t.string:    sa_name
```

Second case:

```
     t.string: receipt_number
  t.timestamp: transaction_timestamp
     t.string: transaction_type
    t.decimal: cash_amount
    t.decimal: card_amount
    t.decimal: voucher_amount
    t.decimal: total_amount
        t.int: sa_id
     t.string: sa_name
```

How can I make alignment as expected code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an admittedly hacky solution in pure vimscript:

```
:%norm dt::left 17<C-v><CR>0:exec "norm R".getreg('"')<C-v><CR>
```

Obviously, you can changed `17` to whatever value works best with your text.

Explanation:

The way this works is by deleting everything up to the first colon before aligning. Then after that, it uses replace mode (`R`) to paste the deleted text over the extra spaces.

```
:%norm                          " On every line:
       dt:                      " Delete until a colon
          :left 17<C-v><CR>     " Align to the 17'th column
```

Then, we move back to the first column with `0` and run the rest. We use `exec` so that we can construct a normal command with the contents of the deleted text.

```
:exec                               " Execute the following string
      "norm                         " Enter normal mode
            R"                      " Enter replace mode
              .                     " Concatenate this string 
               getreg('"')          " With the contents of the unnamed register
                          <C-v><CR> " Enter
```

We use `<C-v><cr>` so that it enters a literal newline rather than running the command right then.

Comment: Your code golf background is showing (paying off?). :P

Comment: @Tumbler41 Hehe, maybe a little. But if I wanted to really golf it I would have used `<C-v><C-r>"` instead of `getreg('"')`

Answer (score 1):

Aligning delimiter is controlled by `stick-to-left` option. Its a boolean controlling whether to position delimiter on the left-side. so your wanted result is achievable through selecting the desired lines with `V`(visual linewise mode) and running the following command:

```
'<,'>EasyAlign : { 'right-margin':0, 'left-margin':3, 'stick-to-left':0 }
```

Of course this is too much typing for a such simple aligment task! In practice you could use interesting **Live interactive mode**. just type `:LiveEasyAlign` command or even faster, map it to a key using `<Plug>(LiveEasyAlign)`. now you can simply using key combinations to align items.

Aligning delimiter is `<Left>` and `<Right>` keys and you can view your code alignment **Live**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what the difficulty is, unless you are *not* aligning using `Space` as delimiter, and/or you don't specify the region to align. Nobody forces you to use `:` as delimiter. Steps:

- Visually select all lines you want (using `V` etc.)
- call your `EasyAlign` key map; the command-line should look like this: `:'<,'>EasyAlign(_)` (if you type the command manually, you need to hit `Enter` once)
- hit `Space`

... That's it, the text is aligned as in your 2nd sample.